# There's always a smaller rational $x$ with $x^2\gt2$

Tags: calculus

Kindly help to prove this problem.

Prove that for every positive rational number $s$ satisfying the condition $s^2 > 2$ one can always find a smaller rational number $s - k (k > 0)$ for which $(s - k) (s - k) > 2.$

Request! I had very big problem in dealing the above type of problems. Once any one can help me out, I am sure I can do such similar problems. Please help me.

Regards and Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have a look at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/464009/given-a-rational-number-x-and-x2-2-is-there-a-general-way-to-find-anothe which is very closely related.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very explicitly (and constructively), you can argue as follows:

Let $s\in\mathbb{Q}_+$, such that $s^2>2$. Let $k=\frac{s^2-2}{2s}>0$, then
$$(s-k)^2 = s^2-2sk+k^2>s^2-2sk = 2.$$

Answer (score 6):

Hint: what happens if you consider the sequence $s-\frac{1}{n}$ for $n\in\mathbb{N}$?

Answer (score 0):

We may assume $\sqrt{2}<s\leq2$. Solving the equation $x^2-2=0$ by Newton's method and starting with $s_0:=s$ gives
$$s_1={1\over2}\left(s+{2\over s}\right)\ .$$
This implies
$$s_1-\sqrt{2}={\bigl(s-\sqrt{2}\bigr)^2\over 2s}={\bigl(s-\sqrt{2}\bigr)\over 2s}\cdot\bigl(s-\sqrt{2}\bigr)\ .$$
Here both factors on the right hand side are positive, and the first one is $<{1\over2}$.